# Replace a substring between two $ with other string

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to replace a substring between two dollars($) with other string using JAVA

```
String original = "my original string $replace_string$";
String toReplace = "test";
```

Now i need the following output

```
my original string test
```

using some regex pattern like

```
original.replace(some_regex, toReplace)
```

Comment: You can check out this link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: try `String resultString = original.replaceAll("\\$(.+)\\$", toReplace);`

Comment: `replaceAll("[$][^$]*[$]",toReplace)`

Comment: You should not use regular expressions for tasks that don’t need regular expressions.  Just use `original.replace("$replace_string$", toReplace)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use regex : `\\$.+?\\$`

```
String mystr = original.replaceAll("\\$.+?\\$",toReplace);
```

- `\$` matches `$` literally
- `.+?` matches every character after `$` reluctantly
- `\$` matches `$` literally